# Read data from file, and store it into an array to output the list

Tags: java, arrays, list, file

what I'm trying to do here is get what is inside of a data/txt file and store it into an array. Right now I'm just trying to do the String, but ultimately I will like to get everything in the file to output. This is what is inside the txt file:

**Honduras 130 Tegucigalpa
Cuba 100 Habanna**

I will like for the output to be the same in java.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ReadCountries2
{
    public static void main(String [] args)throws Exception
    {
       String fName = "/Users/Edward Lavaire/Downloads/Countries.txt";
       Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(fName));

       String name [] = new String[6];

       while(s.hasNext())
       {
           int i = 0;
           name[i] = s.next();
           System.out.println(name[i]);
           i++;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java read file and store text in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844649/java-read-file-and-store-text-in-an-array)

Comment: is there any possible way to do it without <ArrayList> ?

Comment: Probably. But List is by far your best option. It's the java way of storing an arbitrary amount of data. Arrays are fixed size.

Answer (score 1):

You are always writing to `name[0]` because everytime you loop through your `while` you declare:

```
int i = 0;
```

So your `i++` is pretty much useless.

Answer (score 0):

Just put outside the loop the definition of the variable `i` instead to set him to `0`

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ReadCountries2
{
    public static void main(String [] args)throws Exception
    {
       String fName = "/Users/Edward Lavaire/Downloads/Countries.txt";
       Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(fName));

       String name [] = new String[6];
       int i = 0;
       while(s.hasNext())
       {

           name[i] = s.next();
           System.out.println(name[i]);
           i++;
      }
    }
}
```