# Writing an anagram finder (from a word list in a txt file)

Tags: java, arrays, stringbuffer, anagram

I've been trying to code an anagram finder in Java so that in the terminal after compiling all I would have to do is

1. Type in `java Anagramfind list.txt`
2. When prompted type in a word, say `treasure`
3. The program prints an anagram, like `austerer`
4. Another prompt comes up asking if I would like another one (`yes/no`)

The list.txt file has most, if not all, of the words in the English language.

Here's what I have so far...

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class ProjectAnagram {
    public static void main (String[] args throws IOException) {
        //THis here declares an array of strings
        Scanner dictionary = new Scanner new (fileInputStream(args[0]));
        String[] entireArray = new String[173528]; //name of array + 173258
        System.out.println ("Put something in please");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ("Inserted");

        String word = keyboard;
    }
```

I still need to add the rest.

I've mostly been having trouble with the use of arrays, which I referenced here:

- [Java read file and store text in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844649/java-read-file-and-store-text-in-an-array#19844967)
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html
- [What is "String args[]"? parameter in main method Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-parameter-in-main-method-java)

I also am having trouble using a Stringbuffer which to check if words have the same characters or not.

The program checks if the input string and if the string in the text file have the same length first so as to rule out obvious non-anagrams. If it doesn't, then it moves on to the next word in the list, probably with `i++` in some loop.

Comment: Your code is extremely uncompilable. Please fix your code in your post. There are plenty syntactical errors.

Comment: It's actually pseudocode, lol

Comment: If you ask a Java question, please post Java code. This "pseudo-code" is for sure not valid in any question as there are unbalanced parantheses, unbalanced curly braces and so on. Please fix the code in your question.

Comment: If you're planning to go over every element (word in the english language) you should really consider my answer. Storing the dictionary in an array then using the other algorithms below is fairly inefficient especially if the dictionary is alphabetized.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to finding if two strings are permutations of each other, you can sort the characters of the given string and make it the key to a list of anagrams. This way no matter the string you will find only strings of the same length comprised of the same characters.

Something like:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map ...
map.get(getKey(string)).get(i); // i = the ith request for an anagram
```

Comment: Yup, it's working. Thank you for this one!

Comment: @J.Doe, glad to help. If it proves to be the best solution, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Arrays.equals('Testing'.chars().sorted().toArray(), 'ingsetT'.chars().sorted().toArray())
```

Comment: Am I mistakenly misunderstanding the difference between a permutation and an anagram; don't they need to be valid words?

Comment: Granted, `ingsetT` is not a valid anagram, but each anagram is just a permutation that is a new word and OP works with a wordlist.

Comment: So in place of `Testing` and `ingset` I could replace it with variables `word` and `entirearray` from above, respectively?

Comment: I'm not sure, becuase you still didn't fix your code above so it is unclear what is what. But if `word` is the word input by the user and `entirearray` is one of the words of the wordlist, then yes. But form the naming I guess `entirearray` is the whole wordlist, so you would loop over `entirearray` and check each entry with that line, while of course you should not do the `...toArray()` stuff for the input word for each wordlist word, but do it once and reuse.

Comment: And if you often check through the whole wordlist and have enough memory it could be worth calculating the sorted arrays of the wordlist words once after reading the wordlist with a mapping to the original word and then only do the searching repeatedly. You could then even sort the sorted list and use a binary search algorithm or you could pimp your wordlist file with the sorted character to word mapping so that you don't have to do it on each program launch. There are plenty ways to optimize this.

Comment: I removed the unintelligible parts of my code and added that I needed to add missing material :). So say I wanted to take one word from `entireArray`, how would I reference that in the methods?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. If you want to take the 5th word of `entireArray`, that would be `entireArray[4]`. But if that was your question, please go and read a book about Java basics. ;-)

Comment: Sorry, poorly worded question. But you still managed to answer it, so thanks! I though if I was to put in a method afterwards via a `.` I would need parentheses, not brackets.

Comment: Yes, you need parens for a method call, but array element access is no method. As I said, read a book about Java basics.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ProjectAnagram {

    static String sort(String s) {
        char[] c = s.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(c);
        return String.valueOf(c);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Map<String, List<String>> words = new HashMap<>();
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(args[0]))) {
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                String word = in.next();
                String sorted = sort(word);
                List<String> list = words.get(sorted);
                if (list == null)
                    words.put(sorted, list = new ArrayList<>());
                list.add(word);
            }
        }
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter word (or press ENTER to quit): ");
            if (!in.hasNextLine()) break;
            String s = in.nextLine();
            if (s.length() == 0) break;
            System.out.println(words.get(sort(s)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it isn't compiling, for some reason.

Comment: Thank you anyways. Can I ask why it won't compile, though, or why the `static String sort(String s)` is all the way at the top?

Comment: Enclose everything or just `static String sort(String s)`?

Comment: Now it's saying it `cannot find symbol` on various lines.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot to import. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: [This answer is an efficient way to do it!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15045892/4509355)

Hashmaps are O(1) look up time.

We would need 3 iterations. First to add character count in first string to hashmap, second to remove character count in second string from hashmap, third to iterate through hashmap and see if all the values were 0.

So, this would give us an O(n) algorithm.

Comment: So `OO` is an anagram of `NP`? The hashing algorithm is very weak. It could at most serve as indicator, but you would still have to compare the characters.

Comment: @BjörnKautler what if we change it to:

`hash += Math.pow(str.charAt(i),2);`

Comment: Alternatively, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15045892/4509355) seems to work and is efficient

Comment: Well, the hashing is better, but I'm relatively certain it also has many conflicts. You can this make even better using CRC or MD5 or SHA-1, but the safer you make, the more time it needs. You can also just use my one-liner, though I didn't test its performance :-)

Comment: Your one-liner had sorting which will be O(n log n). 

The answer I linked to would store each char from the first string in a hashmap, then remove each char in second string from the hashmap, then it would iterate over the hashmap and see if any values were 0>

This would be O(n).

Comment: As I said, i don't know about its performance, but it will work and it is in just one line. ;-)

Comment: @NishantRoy, but all that does is determine if it's a permutation. They need is a way to get one of n anagrams. They also want to be able to get more upon request.